# how to sum the values from inputs on front end

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have five input elements in my HTML Page:-

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Input 1</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value1">
  <label for="">Input 2</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value2">
  <label for="">Input 3</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value3">
  <label for="">Input 4</label>
  <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value4">
</div>
```

On fifth input I want the sum of first four:-

```
<label for="">Total Value:-</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="input.total">
```

What I want is as soon as user input the value in any of the above input elements its sum appears in `Total Value`.

I wrote the function in my directive code:

```
 scope.totalDeposit = function(){
     scope.input.total = scope.input.value1 + scope.input.value2 + scope.input.value3 + scope.input.value4;
 }

 scope.totalDeposit();
```

I dont want this function to call on ng-blur. Also, The user can input value in any three or two inputs of which he get the sum.
The current code is not showing the sum on front-end.Can anyone suggest me some solution?

Comment: ng-change and sum up the values..

Answer (score 0):

ng-change method and sum up the values.

Comment: Would you mind showing some code demonstrating your idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-value to achieve the effect

```js
angular.module('testapp', [])
  .controller('testController', [function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.value1 = 0;
    vm.value2 = 0;
    vm.value3 = 0;
    vm.value4 = 0;
    vm.value5 = 0;
  }])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="testapp">
  <div ng-controller="testController as testCtrl">

    <label for="">Input 1</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="testCtrl.value1">
    <label for="">Input 2</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="testCtrl.value2">
    <label for="">Input 3</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="testCtrl.value3">
    <label for="">Input 4</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="testCtrl.value4">

    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-value="testCtrl.value1+testCtrl.value2+testCtrl.value3+testCtrl.value4" ng-model="testCtrl.value5">


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: values of inputs are strings so the result will be a concatenation, not sum

Comment: I think they are taking sum please try the code sample

Comment: I didn't notice `type=number` which is handled differently by Angular, you are right

Comment: Total should not be settable. It is a calculated value that only exists as a sum of the 4 inputs.

Comment: If you want to make input 5 unchangeable use readonly attribute

Comment: And if the user opens the inspector, removes the readonly attribute, types in their desired amount (which sets input5 and doesn't equal the total of inputs 1-4) and submits, what happens?

Comment: That's what you should check in server. Since angular is client side code. No matter what you do user can find a way around it

Comment: If you want you can use ng-disabled="value1+..+value4!=value5" in form submit button

Answer (score 0):

There really is no reason to store the total when it can be calculated. Simply have a `<span>` with `ng-bind` to the return value of `$scope.input.total()` and whenever the values inside `$scope.input` change, the value in the span will update automatically. If you want to call the function programmatically from within the controller, it can be done by saying `var total = $scope.input.total()`

Here's how it would look:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.input = {
      value1: "",
      value2: "",
      value3: "",
      value4: "",
      total: function() {
        return (+this.value1) + (+this.value2) + (+this.value3) + (+this.value4);
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Input 1</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value1">
    <br/><label for="">Input 2</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value2">
    <br/><label for="">Input 3</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value3">
    <br/><label for="">Input 4</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="input.value4">
  </div>
  <label for="">Total Value:</label>
  <span type="number" class="form-control" ng-bind="input.total()"></span>
</div>
```